# Using Swift3 Function Parameter in Selector

Tags: ios, swift, first-class-functions

I'm attempting to pass in a function to add as a target to a UIButton in Swift3, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

Here's my code:

```
func updateButtonAction(_ action: () -> (), button: UIButton) {
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(customFunction(action)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func customFunction(_ function: () -> ()) {
    function()
}
```

I'm wrapping a passed in function in another function so I know the class that owns it.

I think the issue is that first class functions in Swift aren't supported in Objective-C and the selector keyword only uses Objective-C functions.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: The duplicate question has the best solution here, although my solution was to avoid first class functions and pass in the selector from another class.

Answer (score 1):

Selector is just a fancy synonym for method name. It's not a closure or a function. It's the name of a method on an Obj-C object. Technically, a selector is a string.

`customFunction(action)` is not a selector. The selector is `customFunction(_:)`.

You are trying to pass an implicit parameter to the selector. That's not how selectors work. You are not calling the method, you are just telling the `UIButton` which method it should call - `UIButton` is calling the method and the button is also specifying the parameters.

If you need to pass some code to the event handler, save it on your instance.

```
var function: (() -> Void)?

func customFunction() {
    self.function?()
}
```

In general it's a good idea to have only one event handler and not change it.

Also note that your example has no need for first class functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My goal was to avoid saving it on the instance.  I was able to solve my problem by passing in the parent object and the selector already created in another class instead of just the function wrapped locally.

Comment: @rmooney I understand what you were trying to do but unfortunately this is a very old API which existed before Obj-C had closures. You can easily subclass `UIButton` and add a method that will take a closure instead (the button can hold it) but in 90% cases the event handlers are connected from storyboards/xibs, therefore most people don't bother with subclasses.

Comment: That's a good option as well, but I ended up not needing it.